# fc-cache: command not found

Tags: 18.04, fonts, .ttf

I've just installed ttf-mscorefonts on ubuntu 18.04 server (not desktop) by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Everything seems to have installed correctly.

Apparently, in order to get the system to recognise these fonts, I need to run

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

However, that throws the following error:

```
sudo: fc-cache: command not found
```

Answer (score 39):

You have to install "fontconfig" package:

```
sudo apt install fontconfig
```

Now you should be able to use `fc-cache`.